# Merge two array and separate array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to separate color, size, material etc where a and b array always same length.

```
a = ["Color", "Color", "color", "color", "Size", "size"]

b = ["black", "red", "blue", "green", "small", "large"]
```

i want

```
output = [['black','red','blue','green'], ['small','large'],...]
```

Comment: and what did you try?

Comment: Will `a` and `b` always be the same length?

Comment: Doesn't the output `{ color: ['black', 'red', 'blue', 'green'], size: ['small', 'large'] }` make more sense?

Comment: yes a and b always same length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of `reduce` and then take values by `Object.values()`:

```js
var a = ["Color", "Color", "color", "color", "Size", "size"];
var b = ["black", "red", "blue", "green", "small", "large"];

var result = Object.values(b.reduce((acc, elem,i)=>{
  const key = a[i].toLowerCase();
  acc[key] = [...(acc[key] || []), elem];
  return acc;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find my answer to your question. It stores in a dictionary first, then converts it to an array.

The below code will also generate the desired result for the cases where Color and Size randomly ordered.

```js
const a = ["Color", "Color", "color", "color", "Size", "size", "color"];
const b = ["black", "red", "blue", "green", "small", "large", "white"];

let dict = [];
for(let i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    let lowerCase = a[i].toLowerCase();
    if(!dict[lowerCase]) {
       dict[lowerCase] = [];
    }
    dict[lowerCase].push(b[i]);
}

let arr = [];
for(let item in dict) {
    arr.push(dict[item]);
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

To merge both arrays you can also use forEach:

```
const a = ["Color", "Color", "color", "color", "Size", "size"];
```

`const b = ["black", "red", "blue", "green", "small", "large"];`
`const newArray = []`

```
const newArray2 = a.forEach((color) => {newArray.push(a+b);console.log(newArray)});
```